# Laravel redirect to route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm using Laravel 5.1 and wanted to know if there is a better way to do routing redirection.

```
Route::get('user/login', 'UserController@login');
Route::get('login', function() {
    return redirect()->to('user/login');
});
```

So basically, whenever a user goes to `http://example.com/login`, they will be redirect to `http://example.com/user/login`.

Is there a better way or other ways to do this or am I doing it correctly already? Thanks!

Comment: Why not do it in the .htaccess?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's about as simple as it gets

You could also do `redirect('user/login')` to save a few characters

If you had multiple redirects like this you could handle them all at once

```
Route::pattern('user_path', '(login|logout)');

Route::get('{user_path}', function($user_path) {
    return redirect('user/' . $user_path);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Route::get('new/create_view','CreateController@create_view');
Route::post('new/create_view','CreateController@insert_view');

Route::get('new/create_table','CreateController@create_table');
Route::post('new/create_table','CreateController@insert_table');


Route::get('new/create_package','CreateController@create_package');
Route::post('new/create_package','CreateController@insert_package');
```

This is the way i am using the route. Simple method. when the time of GET, am calling a controller function and inside that particular controller function, i have written the logical codes. In the POST also, doing the same thing.

Another way is there,GROUP Routing

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin'], function()
{
// Controllers Within The "App\Http\Controllers\Admin" Namespace

Route::group(['namespace' => 'User'], function()
{
    // Controllers Within The "App\Http\Controllers\Admin\User" Namespace
});
});
```

eg:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api/v1', 'before' => 'auth.basic'),         function()
{
Route::resource('pages', 'PagesController', array('only' => array('index',  'store', 'show', 'update', 'destroy')));
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
});
```